# How to use Spring MVC and with React as front end server?

Tags: reactjs, spring-mvc

Can we use Spring MVC (Not spring boot)  as a backend server framework with react as client side to interact?
If then how to perform server side validations.

Comment: What have you tried? For example, this seems to cover the subject: https://medium.com/@pietroghezzi/spring-and-react-js-the-easy-way-5abe8a529058

Comment: Anyone please explain in detail